# Full repository and partial repository channels in MQ

Tags: message-queue, ibm-mq

How the Cluster Sender and Receiver channels usage differs in Full Repository & Partial Repository QManagers in IBM websphere MQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Full Repository:
 - the queue manager's cluster receiver channel must point to itself, this is how other queue managers in the cluster will know how to reach the FR.
 - the cluster sender channel must point to another Full Repository.

On the Partial Repository:
 - the queue manager's cluster receiver channel must also point to itself, this is how other queue managers in the cluster will know how to reach it.
 - the cluster sender channel must point to one of the Full Repository queue managers; this is the FR the PR will rely on for cluster object resolution.

Notes:
1. Your cluster should have 2 Full Repositories; each FR sender channel should point to the other FR.
2. Your Partial Repositories should be configured to point to one of these 2 Full Repositories; a good habit is to equally assign them between the FRs.

Answer (score 1):

A cluster receiver definition is how other qmgrs in the cluster will talk back to that queue manager, it acts like a template of how to talk to the qmgr.

A cluster sender defintion creates the *initial* channel for one queue manager in a cluster to find a full repository for that cluster. This is a manual cluster sender. It doesnt matter whether you are a full or partial repository, you need to have a manual sender pointing to another full repository.

Subsequent connections from one queue manager to another are done using 'auto' cluster senders. A cluster queue manager queries information about a destination it needs to make a connection to (e.g. it hosts a queue that is the destination for a message) from the full repository. The information retrieved is based on the cluster receiver for the destination, hence m comment that a clusrcvr is the 'template' for the connections to that queue manager.